# Strange behavior when splicing array, javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, checkbox

I'm working with list of checkboxes and I have next logic behavior for it:

1. if all items selected, checkbox "select all" is checked
2. if one of all selected items has been unchecked, checkbox "select all" is unchecked as well

This logic is clear. Depends of what item is checked I extract its id to an additional array and then using this array for request that to get data.

For pushing everything works fine, but for slicing the logic is strange. So I can slice the array until first item is checked, however I unchecked the first item, pushed and sliced items no more related with checkboxes.

I have reproduced [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ep4ibyBXGDq1QXMHGFCw?p=preview) with it, so I appreciate if anybody could help me to find what I'm missing.

```
  $scope.modelClass = {
        selectedAll: false
        };

$scope.selectAllClass = function (array) {
     angular.forEach(array, function (item) {
            item.selected = $scope.modelClass.selectedAll;

            $scope.param =''

         });
    };

$scope.checkIfAllClassSelected = function (array) {
     $scope.modelClass.selectedAll = array.every(function (item) {
           return item.selected == true
        });
     $scope.checked = array.filter(function (item) {
           return item.selected == true
        }).length;

     angular.forEach(array, function (obj) {
           if(obj.selected == true){
                requestClass(obj)
            }
       });
   };

   var selectedClass = [];
   var requestClass = function (obj) {

         selectedClass.push(obj);

         angular.forEach(selectedClass, function (val) {
                 if (val.selected != true) {
                      selectedClass.splice(selectedClass.indexOf(val.id), 1);
                 }
                 else {
                      selectedClass = selectedClass.filter(function (elem, index, self) {
                             return index == self.indexOf(elem);
                     })
                 }
            });

          $scope.param = _.map(selectedClass, 'id')
     };




  $scope.classes = [
           {"id":4,"name":"Achievement","selected":false},
           {"id":13,"name":"Information","selected":false},
           {"id":6,"name":"Issue","selected":false},
           {"id":5,"name":"Message","selected":false},
           {"id":9,"name":"Request","selected":false}
           ]
```

Comment: This part is not clear: "Depends of what item is checked I extract its id to an additional array and then using this array for request that to get data".

Comment: @user44 so each item has an unique id, if I checked item with id =4, I'm pushing this id to array, if I unchecked item with id =4, I'm slicing this id from array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic looks good for me, not sure what's wrong here. I've took the first solution from this [post](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2015/10/angular-select-allde-select-all-checkbox.html) (it looks like you are using the second one) and slightly modified it for your needs.

```
$scope.model = {
    selectedClass : []
}

$scope.isSelectAll = function(){
    $scope.model.selectedClass = [];

        if($scope.master){
            $scope.master = true;

          for(var i=0;i<$scope.classes.length;i++){
                        $scope.model.selectedClass.push($scope.classes[i].id);      
                    }
                }
      else{
        $scope.master = false;
      }

   angular.forEach($scope.classes, function (item) {
            item.selected = $scope.master;
   });

   $scope.param = $scope.model.selectedClass
}

$scope.isChecked = function()   {

            var id = this.item.id;

            if(this.item.selected){

                $scope.model.selectedClass.push(id);

                if($scope.model.selectedClass.length == $scope.classes.length ){$scope.master = true;

                }
            }  else  {
                $scope.master = false;

                var index = $scope.model.selectedClass.indexOf(id);

                $scope.model.selectedClass.splice(index, 1);
            }

        $scope.param = $scope.model.selectedClass
    }  


$scope.classes = [
           {"id":4,"name":"Achievement","selected":false},
           {"id":13,"name":"Information","selected":false},
           {"id":6,"name":"Issue","selected":false},
           {"id":5,"name":"Message","selected":false},
           {"id":9,"name":"Request","selected":false}
    ]
```

html

```
<div ng-class="{'selected': master, 'default': !master}">
   <div>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master" ng-change="isSelectAll()" > Select all
   </div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in classes | orderBy : 'id'" ng-class="{'selected': item.selected, 'default': !item.selected}">
   <div >
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-change="isChecked()">
         {{ item.name }}
     </div>
</div>
```

this is fixed [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UEv547KihNCgxOhucuTo?p=preview)